# how to dial phone using java programe

Tags: java, serial-port

when i connect the mobile phone to computer through usb. So then i want to giv commands usin computer program to phone. As a example Dialing number,busy tone to incoming call like that....
i heard AT command can do this kind of things. is there any possibility to do this job using java command and AT command.. what are the recommended from u. & **if u can show me simple code which can dial number using java that will helpfull to me to understand.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect your phone as modem then you can fire AT commands to do the same.
**Check**

- [send-sms-via-at-command-by-using-java](http://www.jiramot.info/send-sms-via-at-command-by-using-java)
- [Java-sending-AT-Commands-GSM](http://www.coderanch.com/t/384169/java/java/Java-sending-AT-Commands-GSM)